# Kafka has multiple bootstrap server but we will connect only one server. Can we still publish data to it?

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka has multiple bootstrap server like b1.com, b2.com, b3.com. While Producer Configuration, we are passing only b1.com as bootstrap server. What will happen once we will publish data to kafka?

As of my knowledge, it should not allow to publish the data if b1.com is not leader as kafka allow publishing data through leader only. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Even if b1.com is not the leader, you would still be able to publish data successfully. The reason being once you connect to a server, you can get the complete metadata of your topic (partitions, their respective leaders etc).

That being said, it is still recommended to provide all servers. Reason for this is the scenario where b1.com goes down. Now since you provided only one server to your producer, it will not be able to connect to kafka and your system effectively goes down.

On the other hand, if you had provided all the servers and assuming your topic was replicated - the system would still be functional even if b1.com had gone down.